# How can I rename a file in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

In my project I want to rename the file before it is updating. For example a file in my system like `Mycontact.xls`. I want to rename it as `sasi.xls` (it is an excel file). How can I write the code in ASP.NET?

Actually I am using a fileupload control to get the file in and rename the file and upload the renamed file in a folder which is in [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# does not provide a file rename function, unfortunately. Anyhow, the idea is to do this:

```
File.Copy(oldFileName, NewFileName);

File.Delete(oldFileName);
```

You can also use - `File.Move`.

Comment: i will try and let you know Mr. Bhaskar. thank you for response

Comment: What is File.Move Mr. Bhaskar can you tell me

Comment: System.IO.File.Move(oldFileName, NewFileName)...this will move the file with a new name (if the soure and destination folder is same and file names are different, then it will act as a rename)

Comment: i am using fileupload then how can i change

Comment: Are you using File Upload from your ASP.NET page? If yes, then you can simply SaveAs a new file name, i.e. fileUpEx.PostedFile.SaveAs(Full Path with a new name);

Comment: yes i am using a file upload mr. bhaskar. for example i have a excel file in desktop which is i am getting using fileupload after that i want to change the name and upload the file in a file which is in solution explorer

Comment: how can it is possible mr.Bhaskar

Comment: ya i got it i write like this 
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs( Server .MapPath ( "~/User/Excel/sasi.xls"));

it is wroking fine thank you

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with the [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) method eg:

```
string oldFileName = "MyOldFile.txt";
string newFileName = "MyNewFile.txt";
File.Move(oldFileName, newFileName);
```

Comment: Hi Winston Smith, i am using fileupload control then how can i write

Comment: actually my requirement is i am getting a excel file from desktop using fileupload then i want to change its name and upload into a folder which is in solution explore

Comment: Thanks Winston Smith,
for file uploading use: System.IO.File.Move(path__1 + fileName, path__1 + newfilename)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that when that code executes, the owner of the file will turn into the identity you have set on your Application Pool on which the website is running.

That account might not have enough permissions to 'create new' or 'delete' files.

I would advise you to place all read/writable files in a seperate location so you can control the security settings seperately on that part. This will also split off the 'only readable files/executables' (like the aspx and such) from the 'read/writable' files.