# ASP.NET FileUpload ReName File Before Upload

Tags: asp.net

I am working with a FileUpload control in ASP.NET.  User is restricted to uploading a certain file name and extension, which already exists on the server.  What I would like to do is upload the user selected file with a different name.  For example, file is monthlyreports.xls on both the server and the workstation.  I would like the workstation version to be uploaded as monthlyreports_user.xls so that it does not overwrite the existing file.

I looked at [How can I rename a file in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160785/how-can-i-rename-a-file-in-asp-net) and tried the File.Copy method but it is not working - I get an error that it can't find the file.

```
Private Sub uploadItems(ByVal vPath As String)
    Dim strRename As String = "monthlyreports_user.xls"

    File.Create(vPath & strRename)

    Try
        If FileBrowse.HasFile Then

            File.Copy(FileBrowse.FileName, strRename)

            FileBrowse.SaveAs(strRename)

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayMsgBox(Me, ex.Message(), "uploadErr")
    End Try
```

FileBrowse is the name of my FileUpload control, vPath is the application installation path on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the `SaveAs` method on the FileUpload control as so:

```
FileBrowse.SaveAs(strRename)
```

The call to `File.Copy` in your code is unnecessary.

Comment: The `File.Copy` command isn't just unnecessary; it won't work. The `FileName` will be the path* of the file on the client, which probably won't exist on the server. (*Or possibly just the name, depending on the browser.)

Answer (score 1):

The `.SaveAs` method already gives you the opportunity to specify a new fileName. This should work

```
 string newfilename = String.Format("{0}_{1}", "My_Prefix_", FileBrowse.FileName)
 FileBrowse.SaveAs(newfilename)
```